# Android: Close dialog window on touch

Tags: android, events, dialog, touch

I'd like to close a dialog window in my android app by simply touching the screen.. is this possible?  If so, how?

I've looked into setting some "onClickEven" on the dialog, but it doesnt exist.

How would this be possible?

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial(android-close-dialog-window-on-touch)](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html) can help you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` which will close the dialog if you touch u=outside the dialog.

Answer (score 14):

If your dialog contains any view try to get the touch events in that view and dismiss your dialog when user touch on that view. For example if your dialog has any Image then your code should be like this.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
//create a layout with imageview
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } 
});
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
{
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        return false;
    }
};
```

And you are done!

Comment: This works. Android studio gives me an error though because the "dialog may not have been initialized". To avoid that just replace dialog.dismiss() with this.dismiss()

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Dialog` class and override `dispatchTouchEvent()` method.

**EDIT**: Also you can implement `Window.Callback` interface and set it as dialog's window callback using `dialog.getWindow().setCallback()`. This implementation should call corresponding dialog's methods or handle events in its own way.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still searching for a solution to dismiss a Dialog by
onTouch Event, here is a snippet of code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(MyActivity.this){

                    @Override
                    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
                    {
                        dismiss();
                        return false;
                    }

                };
                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.MyIcon);
                dialog.setTitle("MyTitle");
                dialog.setMessage("MyMessage");
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.show();

        }
```