# Is there a way to dismiss a dialog when the user clicks the transparent area around it?

Tags: android, dialog, touch, transparent, dismiss

I have a few little custom dialogs in my app, and they are kinda small. I've noticed that the user touches the area around the dialog to try to dismiss it (similar to interaction on a website). I was wondering if there are any built in methods for doing this that I must have missed in the doc, or if there are any tutorials out there on how to approach implementing this?

I don't think I'm explaining this well, so if anyone doesn't understand what I'm talking about I will try to provide more information.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Found the answer in a question linked by Balaji:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: did you try setCancelable(true) ? Is it what you are asking for?

Comment: I'm afraid I already have it set to true, but the user has to still click the back button to dismiss it.

Comment: You can check same post over here:

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801634/android-close-dialog-window-on-touch

Comment: It wasn't the accepted answer, but the answer was there. Thank you :)

"dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);"

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in a question linked by Balaji:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```