# TouchEvent in a Dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog

Hi I'm developing an app in which I'm using a dialog on an activity. The dialog will just display a picture and when the user touch on the picture the dialog should dismiss and the activity which started the dialog should come in front. **The Dialog doesn't have any buttons**.

My problem in this app is that **I can't get the touch events on the dialog**, I tried searching on the internet for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find a proper way to implement it. So can any one please suggest a way of doing this...

Comment: Thanks and I've chosen the correct answers for all my questions.

Comment: nice.... because that even makes it more appealing for users to answer your question..... and for this question?? still any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this..

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
   //craete a layout with imageview
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View View3) {
             //your onclick functionality
         } });

        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, and can you suggest me that how to display a Dialog in full screen with out title bar.

Comment: See this link.. i think it will help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362723/how-can-i-get-a-dialog-style-activity-window-to-fill-the-screen

Comment: The solution in this question is for an activity, but in my app I need a full screen for a Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe settings a View.OnClickListener on the main layout element in your Dialog would do the trick :-)

Example code:

```
    public class DialogActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dialogMainLayout);
            linearlayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

dialog.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:id="@+id/dialogMainLayout"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:background="#FFFFF0"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

First i tried just making an activtiy that would start another themed as a dialog. Click the dialog themed activity did absolutely nothing. So i thought that setting an onclicklistener on the root layout element in the xml-file used in the dialog themed activity might solve the problem.

I got the above code working. Hope it fixes your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code, but I want them in a Dialog instead of an Activity like Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[Android: Close dialog window on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801634/android-close-dialog-window-on-touch)

This question might provide an answer to your question.  Alternatively, you can use LayoutInflater to create a custom view that contains an ImageButton or ImageView with an OnClickListener and AlertDialog.Builder and its setView method to make this view the body of your Dialog.